# How do I create the correct route values for this ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink, routevalues

The Model of `SearchResults.aspx` is an instance of `PersonSearch`; when the request for a new page arrive (a GET request), the action method should take it and compute the new results.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult SearchResults(PersonSearch search, int? page)
{
    ViewData["Results"] = new PaginatedList<Person>(_searchService.FindPersons(search), page ?? 0, 1);
    return View("SearchResults", search);
}
```

Then I have to generate the previous/next links:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Next Page >", "SearchResults", routeValues) %>
```

If I use `routeValues = ViewData.Model` I can see the object properties passed the address, but I can't add the "page" parameter.

Answer (score 26):

It think it would be better to create another object with the correct values, instead of using (and potentially altering the current routevalues):

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Next Page >", "SearchResults", new {
    search = this.Model,
    page = 1 //or whatever
}) %>
```

Comment: I get: SearchResults?search=RegistryManager.Models.PersonSearch&page=1

Comment: Does not work...it passes the name of the class, not the key/values pairs corresponding to the object properties...

Answer (score 6):

This blog post by Scott Guthrie helped me wrap my head around URL Routing: [**ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 2): URL Routing**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

[image]
[image]

I love that he included test cases!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to override ToString().

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Razor (I realize OP asked four years ago before Razor was invented, but people finding this maybe using it).

I was able to get something working by using an inline @helper method.

```
@helper RunnerLink(PersonSearch model, int page)
{
    var routeParms =new RouteValueDictionary(model.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(model, null)));
    routeParms.Add("page", page.ToString());
    routeParms.Add("Controller", "Property");
    @Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", routeParms)
}
```

Usage would be simple --

```
@RunnerLink(myPersonSearchInstance, 1)
```

It isn't the most elegant solution, but it works well if you want to pass an object in as a routeValue, but you need to pass additional items, such as `Controller`, `Area` or in OPs case `page`.

Answer (score 1):

You need use RouteLink instead ActionLink. Your code should look something like this

```
@Html.RouteLink("Next", new {controller = "SearchResults", action = "Index", search=samevalue, page=1 })
```