# html.actionlink routevalues error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink, routevalues

recently I have been trying to add a link that allows people to delete their own comments on my website. I have followed the advice of the answer of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810063/html-actionlink-routevalues). This is what my code looks like now:

```
@Html.ActionLink("x","DeleteComment", "Videos", new { commentID = 1234, actionReturnName = "[action]" })
```

Then I have the controller handle the values here:

```
public ActionResult DeleteComment(int commentID, string actionReturnName)
{
    DB.CommentDB.DeleteComment(commentID);

    return RedirectToAction(actionReturnName);
}
```

This seems to be the right way to do it, but what am I doing wrong?
I keep getting this error

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'commentID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteComment(Int32, System.String)'

I might be missing something really stupid, but if you could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload. Right now you're passing in your routeValues as the htmlAttributes.

Pass in an extra null as the htmlAttributes to call the correct method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("x","DeleteComment", "Videos", new { commentID = 1234, actionReturnName = "[action]" }, null)
```